# Failable Init - Variable 'self.customerType' used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've read up and down regarding this, and understand the basics here - I just can't understand why I get this error. I use the second init to instantiate a customer from Firebase, but even if I comment out everything inside it, I still get the error

`Variable 'self.customerType' used before being initialized` at the declaration of init?

```swift
class Customer {

    enum customerTypes {
        case consumer
        case business
    }

    // MARK - properties

    var id: String?
    let customerType: customerTypes
    var name1: String
    var name2: String?
    var address: Address?
    var phone: String?
    var email: String?

    struct Address {
        var street: String
        var postalCode: String
        var city: String
        var country: String = "Norway"
    }

    init(type: customerTypes, name1: String, name2: String?, phone: String, email: String, address: Address? ) {
        self.customerType = type
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.address = address
    }

     init?(data: [String: Any]) {

        guard let type = data["customerType"] as? String else { return }
        guard let name1 = data["name1"] as? String  else { return }

        self.customerType = type == "Consumer" ? .consumer : .business
        self.name1 = name1


//      if let name2 = data["name2"] as? String { self.name2 = name2 }
//      if let phone = data["phone"] as? String { self.phone = phone }
//      if let email = data["email"] as? String{ self.email = email }
//      if let address = data["address"] as? [String: Any] {
//          let street = address["street"] as? String
//          let postCode = address["postCode"] as? String
//          let city = address["city"] as? String
//          if street != nil && postCode != nil && city != nil {
//              self.address = Address(street: street!, postalCode: postCode!, city: city!)
//          }
//      }

    }
```

What simple issue am I overlooking here?

Comment: show the `customerType` and other properties in the `Customer `.

Comment: You have not declared any of your properties, `var customerType: customerTypes` `var name1: String` and so on

Comment: Updated with properties declaration

Comment: That error is fairly straightforward. You're attempting to use `Customer.type` somewhere in code prior to creating `Customer.type`. For proof in your default `init()` set a default value.

Comment: The variable customerType is declared the same way as e.g name1, name2 etc. Why is setting this variable any different? And as you can see, the error appears for the second init? without any code, not the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare an initializer which promises to either return an initialized `Customer` or no `Customer` (because it is fallible). You alo declare `let customerType: customerTypes` as one of the properties of the class.

That means that if you successfully return from the initializer (that means, not returning `nil`), this property has to be initialized to some value.

The error is not very helpful in the location of the error, as the error is actually on the line below. By simply putting `return` in your `guard`, you are saying that your object is successfully initialized, which it is not, as you have not yet set `customerType` to a value.

So if you put a `return nil` in your `guard` clause, you will say that your initialization failed, and then you do not need to put a value in `customerType`.

Answer (score -1):

The properties that don't have an initial value needs to set inside an `init`. You can fix the issue by either setting them as `Optional` or by setting a default value:

```swift
init?(data: [String: Any]) {
    customerType = .consumer
    name1 = ""
}
```

or:

```
var customerType: customerTypes?
var name1: String?
```

Note: By setting the properties `Optional` the compiler assumes that the initial value is `nil`.

Comment: I see, but i've tried to fix this with a guard let, but my error still occurs. Hard coding it works, but not using the guard let statement
`init?(data: [String: Any]) {
  
  guard let type = data["customerType"] as? String else { return }
  guard let name1 = data["name1"] as? String  else { return }
  
  self.customerType = type == "Consumer" ? .consumer : .business
  self.name1 = name1`